# Writing encrypted syslogs

Tags: encryption, logging

I have a request to find out if there is a way to store syslog messages encrypted.  I don't have a problem with making logrotate (or a bash script) encrypt messages nightly, but is there a way that I can stream encrypted syslog messages?  I thought this seemed like overkill and I didn't see any plugins or documentation from syslog-ng, so I'm guessing this'd have done with some other way.

Barring this, is there a better way to work around this, and placate the people who are making this request.  They want at-rest encryption of the log files so whether or not the volume is encrypted is apparently unimportant to them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to tunnel it using HTTPS/TLS with mutual authentication, is good practice especially, if confidentiality of the logs are important. 
With logrotate (compress, [encrypt with GPG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50368056/12534623)) & TLS you will be well covered for both data-at-rest and in-transit use cases.

Here is some [official syslog-ng guidance](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.17/administration-guide/55) how to set up TLS connection between the syslog server and client, make sure certificate management is in place as well.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  What I want to know is if it is possible to encrypt the logs, not the archives or the transport